# Windows 10 Task Scheduler run job but not launch new window

Tags: task-scheduler

I have a Task Scheduler job that run a Batch file containing python script. When this job is activated either automatically or manually, the script runs correctly as I can see output file generated. The only thing is that when the job run, there is NO new windows is launched. So I have to go to output folder to check if output file is created to verify if the job is running.
How do I fix this problem?

I have the same setup running the same script using Task Scheduler on other machine and yes, new window is launched. That window contain details of log, printout of the python script.

Answer (score 0):

When you runs things using the task scheduler they run non-interactively, which means no user interface.

Here is some guidance how to run a task interactively under a user session
https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2021/05/01/running-application-in-an-interactive-session-from-a-non-interactive-one-without-admin-privileges/index.html

```
schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC MONTHLY /D 1 /TN "YourTaskName" /TR "Your Task Command" /ST 03:01 /f /RU UserName
schtasks /run /tn "YourTaskName" /i
```